# Create points along a line from spreadsheet data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, spreadsheet

I have a sewer network comprising:

- Manholes - a points layer
- Pipes - a polyline layer, with attributes comprising the upstream and downstream manhole

I have a spreadsheet of pipe defects (from a CCTV contractor), where each defect is identified by the following data.  Each defect is logged on a separate line with the following attributes:

- Pipe ID
- Starting Manhole
- Ending Manhole
- Distance from Starting manhole
- A range of attributes on observations made

I want to create a set of points for each defect so that I can then analyse the defects.  As there can be a huge number of defects, I want to create a workflow to bring the points into QGIS so I can prioritise them.

I can see how to generate points at vertices, crossings or equidistant.  However I am not certain where to even start in this task.

Comment: You may want to read on Linear referencing or Dynamic Segmentation (see the LRS plugin to implement that in QGIS) as it may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Try QGIS' natively supported *SpatiaLite* SQL; create a [*Virtual Layer*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) with:

```
SELECT d.<pipe_id_column>,
       d.<other_columns>,
       ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(p.geometry, <distance_from_start_column> / ST_Length(p.geometry, <TRUE | FALSE>)) AS geometry
FROM   <pipe_layer> AS p
JOIN   <defects_layer> AS d
  ON   p.<id> = d.<pipe_id_column>
;
```

Here, a *Point* will be created (interpolated) at the fraction of line length given by the `Distance to Starting Manhole` divided by total line length (see below).

Fill in `<>` wrapped identifiers with actual layer/column names; `ST_Length` accepts a boolean parameter (see below).

The CSV can be loaded into the project or referred to as external data source in the *Virtual Layer* dialog.

---

This assumes a few things:

- the `Starting Manhole` **always corresponds with the start node** of the respective *LineString*

  *If that is not necessarily the case, please edit your question with that info and maybe leave a comment here*
- all geometries are in the same CRS
- CRS is **geographic (LonLat)**, e.g. *EPSG:4326*

  **Note:**
  When a boolean parameter is passed to `ST_Length`, the function will calculate length either on a *sphere* (`FALSE`; faster, less precise) or a *spheroid* (`TRUE`; slower, highest precision), and results are in *meter*! **This needs to match the `Distance from Starting Manhole` unit**. 
  If the CRS is projected **do not pass the second parameter**, to get length calculated using the given CRS and its units.